# Will 'release-upgrade' to 18.04.1 LTS Server on Raspberry Pi 3B provide a 64bit Kernel

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu, 64-bit

I have Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS Server (for armvhf) installed on my Raspberry Pi 3B (ARMv8), which runs a 32bit kernel.  I would like to install a 64bit kernel and associated modules with minimal fuss as I have a lot of things on my Pi I don't want to mess up.

Will performing `apt do-release-upgade` lead to a 64bit kernel? Any tips of what to expect?

Comment: Welcome. What reason do you have to believe it would?  If you don't have any, it might be better to ask for the easiest way to what you want in context.